# Does ASP.NET Core's authentication middleware always use implicit flow for OpenID Connect?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Setting up a simple out-of-the-box ASP.NET Core MVC app in Visual Studio 2019 with authentication enabled against an Azure Active Directory will result in implicit OAuth2 flow while using OpenID-Connect.

This is illustrated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp).

[image: Implicit flow]

I just tested this and I did not have to deal with a client secret which would be mandatory for authorization code flow, so I presume above is true.

On the other hand in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#is-the-implicit-grant-suitable-for-my-app) the use of the implicit flow is discouraged:

> The implicit grant presents more risks than other grants, [...] If you
>   are developing a Web application that includes a backend, and
>   consuming an API from its backend code, the implicit flow is also not
>   a good fit.

To further confuse things, there is [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) where it is stated that web apps are using the authorisation code flow:

> The OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow is described in section 4.1 of
>   the OAuth 2.0 specification. It's used to perform authentication and
>   authorization in the majority of app types, including web apps and
>   natively installed apps.

The questions that arise are

- If the implicit flow is considered a bad choice, why is it used by the ASP.NET Core MVC middleware?
- Can I change the behaviour?
- If yes, where and how would I be able to obtain the client secret from Azure AD's app registration?

Comment: Actually, implicit flow was designed for single page application. So far I know you have to follow the pattern as per official docs. For client secret you have register app  on azure portal  under `Certificates & secrets` option you would get application secret that is client secret. Here is example how you would get [client secret](https://imgur.com/a/p1yn8Gm)

Comment: Really depends what you are trying to do, while settings up apsnet core app from visual studio template it will show up with authentication code not implicit grant flow.

Comment: Another point here is that for the Azure B2C MVC web example to work, you must explicitly enable return of access tokens by checking the "Access tokens (used for implicit flows)" in addition to the ID tokens checks box on the authentication page of your app registration--despite this going against their documentation recommendations elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observations are, unfortunatelly valid.

The samples provided use implicit flow. I would guess for simplicity. This can be seen from the [configuration script for the latest sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/AppCreationScripts/Configure.ps1).

All the statements regarding implicit flow are correct. Including the one from the comment.

However, we have to pay attention, that the default scaffolding of ASP.NET Core project that uses OpenID Connect, actually only performs *authentication* and not *authorization*. It also does not perform a calls to external APIs. In that sense, the implicit flow is used to only obtain an `id_token`, but not `access_token`. The former contains user profile information and does not pose security risk. Whereas the latter contains authorization data for accessing specific resource.  So the id_token itself does not impose a security risk when leaked. Yes it imposes data leak if leaked, but not a security one.

There is more complete sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore). Which uses ob-behalf-of flow to get an `access_token` to call external service. It is still not the full authorization code grand flow, but the on-behalf-of flow. The latter is even more secure.

Generally speaking OpenIDConnect implementation in .NET Core does have implementation for handling authorization code, which can be seen from the [AuthorizationCodeRecieved event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.onauthorizationcodereceived?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_OpenIdConnect_OpenIdConnectEvents_OnAuthorizationCodeReceived). Which can be used when constructing [OpenIdConnectOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) object by defining the [OpenIDConnectEvents property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Frankly, to ask why project scaffolds are so designed will not bring a lot of attention, neither will it change it something. I am pretty sure the older implementations (.net 4.5 or so) were using AuthZ Code by default. Not sure why this has changed - probably to lower the friction of implementation and understanding of samples ....

But hey, IMO using Authorization Code grand to just get an ID token is a bit of an overkill, isn't it?

***Addressing the comments***

1) Agree it is a mess. Authorize attribute does nothing but checking for *authenticated* user. It may also be configured to check for a specific role. But even then, that role will be extracted from the `id_token`. Because you do not have `access_token` in case of a web app. My point is, thet when you deal with a simple web app (front end, backend - Controllers or ASPX pages) you only deal with id_tokens and no access tokens. In that context having implicit flow significantly reduces the code complexity.

The documentation is open sourced on GitHub and any responsible programmer has the freedom (and is more then welcome) to suggest improvements or indicate problems. While StackOverflow is for technical questions and answers, not complaints about software documentation.

Comment: If you say the sample is using authentication but not authorization what exactly do you mean? Because the controller in the example has got an authorize attribute on it. It’s a bit of a mess: because in this case it only checks for authentication! But it could be changed to check for a specific role for example. Are your arguments still valid in that case?

Comment: Implicit flow does not work for web apps (not SPA) at all. In that flow tokens are returned in a fragment and, except for some browsers do not end in the back-end - they are retained by the browser. Your documentation comments pertain to OAuth2, not OIDC, which is the only one dealing with id tokens. I think what your questioning is why id_token is returned with the code rather than only in response to /token request using auth code. Is that correct?